# Pivot_Longer multiple columns based on the column ending

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a very large datasets with hundreds of columns and hundreds of thousands of rows. I have 5 years of data but the years are in the column names (e.g. columns: column1.2015, column1.2016, column1.2017, column1.2018, column1.2019,). Column names are irregular but always end with 4 digit year. I would like to pivot_longer this data.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame (id  = c("a", "b", "c"),
  column1.2015  = c("1", "2", "3"),
                  column1.2016 = c("4", "5", "6"),
                  column1.2017 = c("4", "5", "6"),
                  column1.2018 = c("4", "5", "6"),
                  column1.2019 = c("4", "5", "6"),
                  column2.2015  = c("1", "2", "3"),
                  column3.2016 = c("4", "5", "6"),
                  column4.2017 = c("4", "5", "6"),
                  column5.2018 = c("4", "5", "6"),
                  column6.2019 = c("4", "5", "6")
)
```

Desired Output:
[image]

I am completely lost, so any help would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @Mike offers a great solution in their answer below, but whatever approach you take, you won't achieve your desired output from your example data. Maybe either update your example data, or your desired output? For instance, are your column3.n - column6.n variables all supposed to be column2.n? Updating your question will benefit others who may come across this in future. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to `pivot_longer()` first and then `separate()` your column names and then `pivot_wider()` on the values you want as columns like so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- pivot_longer(df, cols = -id) %>% 
      separate(col = name, into = c("col","year")) %>% 
      pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, year), names_from = col, values_from = value)
```